# How to make <v-row> start at the top of <v-container> in Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuetify.js

I'm trying to set to create a `<v-row>` inside a `v-container` block, and I want to vertically align it to the top. I feel like it should be as easy, just by adding `align="start"` to `<v-row>`. However this doesn't work, the `<v-row>` is always vertically aligned in the middle of the page.
Here's my code:

```html
<template>
  <v-container fill-height fluid class="accent pa-0">
    <v-row align="start" class="primary"> <v-sheet height="300"></v-sheet></v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Here's how it looks:
[image: Picture]
I want the grey `<v-sheet>` to be under the navbar, at the start of red `<v-container>`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `align-start` to the v-container class you'll get your expected result.

```html
<template>
  <v-container fill-height fluid class="accent pa-0 align-start">
    <v-row align="start" class="primary"> <v-sheet height="300"></v-sheet></v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```